# HiddenFor hace que me genere un valor null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, oracle-11g

He colocado un campo ID_Charla en donde ya me coloca el valor por defecto, al momento de presionar el botón de registrar me bota un error que dice que no se puede ingresar valores nulos. Esto pasa cuando oculto el campo ID_Charla, pero cuando lo pongo visible y presiono el botón de registrar, NO ME BOTA ningún error y se registra en la base de datos. Me gustaría saber cuál es el problema.

**Vista Interesado**

```
@model wsCharlas.Models.ClsInteresado

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CrearInteresado";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>CrearInteresado</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ClsInteresado</h4>

    <hr />
    <strong>DATOS DEL PARTICIPANTE:</strong>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dni_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dni_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dni_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.edad_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.edad_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.edad_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.correo_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.correo_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.correo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.depar_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.depar_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.depar_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.provin_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.provin_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.provin_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dist_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dist_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dist_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <strong>DATOS DE LA CHARLA:</strong>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.id} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Charla:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.titulo" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Descripcion:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.descripcion" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Fecha:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.fecha" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Hora:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.hora" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Direccion:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.direccion" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "MostraCharlas", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Controlador**

```
//Interesados
    public ActionResult CrearInteresado(string id, string titulo, string descripcion, string fecha, string hora, string direccion)
    {

        //==============ENVIAR DATOS A LA VISTA==================
        ViewBag.id = id;
        ViewBag.titulo = titulo;
        ViewBag.descripcion = descripcion;
        ViewBag.fecha = fecha;
        ViewBag.hora = hora;
        ViewBag.direccion = direccion;
        //=======================================================

        return View(new ClsInteresado());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CrearInteresado(ClsInteresado interesado)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.mensaje = "Datos Invalidos";
            return View(new ClsInteresado());
        }

            ViewBag.mensaje = "Datos Validos";

            ClsConexion con = new ClsConexion();
            var Cnx = con.Conexion();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SIMEXA_SP_REGISTRAR_INTERESADO", Cnx);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_DNI", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.dni_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_Ape_pat", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.apePat_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_Ape_mat", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.apeMat_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_nombres", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.nombres_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_fech_naci", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.fecha_nac_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_edad", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.edad_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_sexo", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.sexo_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_correo", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.correo_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_telefono", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.telefono_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_direc", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.direccion_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_dept", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.depar_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_prov", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.provin_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_dist", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.dist_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_id_charla", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = interesado.ID_charla;
            Cnx.Open();

            OracleTransaction tx = Cnx.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tx.Commit();

            Cnx.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            Cnx.Dispose();

            return View(interesado);

    }
```

**Clase Interesado**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace wsCharlas.Models
{
    public class ClsInteresado
    {
        public string ID_Inter { get; set; }
        public string dni_Inter { get; set; }
        public string apePat_Inter { get; set; }
        public string apeMat_Inter { get; set; }
        public string nombres_Inter { get; set; }
        public string fecha_nac_Inter { get; set; }
        public string edad_Inter { get; set; }
        public string sexo_Inter { get; set; }
        public string correo_Inter { get; set; }
        public string telefono_Inter { get; set; }
        public string direccion_Inter { get; set; }
        public string depar_Inter { get; set; }
        public string provin_Inter { get; set; }
        public string dist_Inter { get; set; }
        public string ID_charla { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo dos soluciones, una puedes asignarle el valor de tu ViewBag al modelo antes de asignarlo al hidden:

```
@{
   model.ID_charla = ViewBag.id;
}

    <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_charla)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

Otra forma de solucionarlo sin mover mucho código sería seguir utilizando un editor es poner el "div" invisible de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.id} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda saludos.

Comment: Tu segunda solución fue la mejor de todas :D, gracias amigo @Alfredo